# how to add a login form for user in existing wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

**want to add a login form**
I'm making a web site using WordPress. Is there a way to add a Login page in the WordPress theme? If yes, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

check out word press plugin [BAW Login/Logout menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-login-logout-menu/) which provide login / log out at front end.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [wordpress template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/page-templates/) file for custom login page.

Add a login form in this template.

After form submit use [wp_signon](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function for user login.